# PHP And AJAX Download of a few MB file freezes website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, youtube

Hello ive searched everywhere to find the answer however none of the solutions ive tried helped

What i am building is a site which connects to Youtube to allow users to search and download videos as MP3 files. I have built the site with the search etc however i am having a problem with the download part (ive worked out how to get the youtube audio file). The format for the audio is originally audio/mp4 so i need to convert it to mp3 however first i need to get the file on the server

So on the download page ive made a script that sends an ajax request to the server to start downloading the file. It then sends a request to a different page every few seconds to find out the progress and update it on the page the user is viewing.

However the problem is while the video is downloading the whole website freezes (all the pages dont load until the file is fully downloaded) and so when the script tries to find out the progress it cant until its fully done.

The file which downloads:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['yt_vid']) && isset($_GET['yrt'])) {
    set_time_limit(0); // to prevent the script from stopping execution
    include "assets/functions.php";
    define('CHUNK', (1024 * 8 * 1024));
    if ($_GET['yrt'] == "gphj") {
        $vid = $_GET['yt_vid'];
        $mdvid = md5($vid);
        if (!file_exists("assets/videos/" . $mdvid . ".mp4")) { // check if the file already exists, if not proceed to downloading it
            $url = urlScraper($vid); // urlScraper function is a function to get the audio file, it sends a simple curl request and takes less than a second to complete
            if (!isset($_SESSION[$mdvid])) {
                $_SESSION[$mdvid] = array(time(), 0, retrieve_remote_file_size($url));
            }
            $file = fopen($url, "rb");
            $localfile_name = "assets/videos/" . $mdvid . ".mp4"; // The file is stored on the server so it doesnt have to be downloaded every time
            $localfile = fopen($localfile_name, "w");
            $time = time();
            while (!feof($file)) {
                $_SESSION[$mdvid][1] = (int)$_SESSION[$mdvid][1] + 1;
                file_put_contents($localfile_name, fread($file, CHUNK), FILE_APPEND);
            }
            echo "Execution time: " . (time() - $time);
            fclose($file);
            fclose($localfile);
            $result = curl_result($url, "body");
        } else {
            echo "Failed.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Since you are using sessions, you cannot go to another page which uses sessions whenever you please. You need to implement `session_write_close();` if you wish to navigate away from a page which has initiated and AJAX call that uses a session. It's not freezing, it's behaving precisely how it is designed to behave.

Comment: session_write_close in the file called by the ajax before it goes into what runs long

Comment: Are you using PHPs standard session handler? You may be experiencing session locking

Comment: Yes i found it on the internet of course 8| ive been self teaching PHP for only about 2 years so im not some expert at it. I cant learn from nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had that problem in the past, the reason that it does not work is because the session can only be once open for writing. 
What you need to do is modify your download script and use `session_write_close()` each time directly after writing to the session.

like:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION[$mdvid])) {
    $_SESSION[$mdvid] = array(time(), 0, retrieve_remote_file_size($url));
}
session_write_close();
```

and also in the while

```
while (!feof($file)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[$mdvid][1] = (int)$_SESSION[$mdvid][1] + 1;
    session_write_close();
    file_put_contents($localfile_name, fread($file, CHUNK), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Why do you say so? I started writing this answer before your other comments, and you say the same thing?

Comment: An monkeyzeus you have 0 respect for other people

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped :P i thought it would be something stupid like this :redface:

Comment: No problem, its usually something small and annoying that keeps giving you headaches :)

Comment: haha true :) ive fixed up the script and is now working as i want it to thanks so much again !!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Either explain what's actually wrong with the solution or keep your bad attitude to yourself.  "You have zero clue what you're doing" is completely non-constructive and unhelpful.